# fatal error: sha256.h: No such file or directory

Tags: arduino, esp8266, sha256, nodemcu

I compile a sketch in Arduino IDE, the code includes sha256.h library:

```
...  
#include "sha256.h"
...
```

When the codes are compiled, the error says:

```
fatal error: sha256.h: No such file or directory
```

I try to install sha256 library from **Sketch** > **Include Library** > **Manage Libraries**, but there are no such library listed.

Where can I get the included library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having more information like the names of some of the functions being called that need this header file it's hard to pin it down. There are several Arduino libraries out there that have a sha256.h header file.

You might try:

[ESP8266-Arduino-cryptolibs](https://github.com/CSSHL/ESP8266-Arduino-cryptolibs) - not available through the library manager, so you'd copy this manually into the Arduino libraries folder

"AWS-SDK-ESP8266" - available through the library manager

There are others that aren't ESP8266-specific; a simple Google search for 'sha256.h esp8266' or 'sha256.h arduino' will find them.

Comment: I tried ["Cryptosuite"](https://github.com/jjssoftware/Cryptosuite) - not available through the library manager, and it solved the problem